# Como comprobar un id que llega por params en bases de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, backend, sequelize, uuid

tengo el siguiente problema...

Estoy armando el backend para un app de videojuegos. Me traigo data desde una api externa y a su vez tengo mi base de datos con dos modelos. En uno de éstos seteé el ID como UUID y por default UUIDV4. Dejo abajo el código:

```javascript
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
// Exportamos una funcion que define el modelo
// Luego le injectamos la conexion a sequelize.
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  // defino el modelo
  sequelize.define('videogame', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      // validate: {
      //   isUUID: 4,
      // },
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    released: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    },
    platforms: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    },
    background_image: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    timestaps: false,
  });
};
```

En una de las rutas, me llega el id por params (que va a ser para renderizar una card sola con todos los detalles de la misma en el front).

Como la página va a tener la opción tanto de consultar información de una tarjeta traída desde la api externa, como así también de crear vos tu propio videojuego (que se va a guardar en la base de datos), hice dos funciones por separado. Una con un axios a la de la api externa:

```javascript
const getVideogameById = async (id) => {
  const response = (await axios(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games/${id}?key=${API_KEY}`)).data
  const { background_image, name, genres, description, released, rating, parent_platforms } = response

  const videogame = {
    background_image,
    name,
    genre: genres.map(g => g.name),
    description,
    released,
    rating,
    platforms: parent_platforms.map(p => p.platform.name)   
  };

  return videogame;
}
```

y otra con un findByPk a la DB. Ambas van a recibir el id como argumento:

```javascript
const videogameByIdDB = async (id) => {
  const videogameFromDB = await Videogame.findByPk(id)
  return videogameFromDB;
}
```

En la ruta, lo que hago es comprobar si el id que me está llegando matchea con el id de la api o con el de la base de datos:

```javascript
const getVideogamesById = router.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params

  try {
    const fromAPI = await getVideogameById(id)
    const fromDB = await videogameByIdDB(id)

    id === fromDB.id ? 
    res.json(fromAPI) : 
    res.json(fromDB) 

  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
});
```

pero el problema es que, si le paso un integer a la ruta por params (que sería el que viene desde la api) la función de la base de datos me toma ese integer y me tira un error cuando hago el get a la ruta: *la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo uuid: «3498»*
Y si le paso un UUID (que me creé una tabla con UUIDV4 para hacer las pruebas) me tira:
*Request failed with status code 404* y en la consola tira un error de axios.

Supongo yo que el problema es que el id que llega por params lo están tomando las dos funciones, tanto la de la api como la de la base de datos y por lo tanto, como cada una espera un tipo de dato específico, cuando no lo recibe, crashea.

Los controllers las estoy mandando a la ruta del index.js de mi carpeta routes:

```javascript
const { Router } = require('express');
const { getVideogames, getVideogamesById } = require('../controllers/videogamesController.js');

const router = Router();

router.use('/videogames', getVideogames); // me voy a traer  todo lo que venga desde la api y desde la db
router.use('/videogame/', getVideogamesById)

module.exports = router;
```

Ya busqué por todos lados y todas las formas, pero no se me ocurre ni encuentro nada que me pueda solucionar ese inconveniente. Alguno tiene una idea?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Coloca tu solucion como respuesta por favor

Comment: Hecho! Gracias por la corrección

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO!

Estaba haciendo mal la comprobación el la función getVideogamesById.
Comparto cómo me quedó:

```javascript
const getVideogamesById = router.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params

  try {
    const regex = /([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+)/
    if (regex.test(id)) {
      const fromDB = await videogameByIdDB(id)
      return res.json(fromDB)
      
    } else  {
      const fromAPI = await getVideogameById(id)
      console.log(fromAPI)
      return res.json(fromAPI)
    } 

  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
});
```